# Analyze bitmap and display the type of geometric shape.

Tags: c#, image-processing, system.drawing, bitmapimage, system.drawing.imaging

I need to develop a **console application in C#** which gets the name of a **bitmap image** as a parameter in main function. The application must analyze the image content from the file and **display to console the type of geometric shape and its color.** 
Conditions:
- Only uncompressed BMP files **containing only primary forms**: rectangle, square and triangle
- Images contain one form or more
- **Forms are primary colors** - RGB and white background is no transparency
- Can not be used other libraries than those provided by **Visual Studio** for C #
- The application can receive on the command line one picture or more

So, i'm using Drawing library and i want to make a matrix of bmp's pixels. After that, i'll cross this matrix and i'll discover the figure inside the image. 
I find the first pixel that's not white (only the background is white) and then I trace the colored path right and down(two figures cannot intersect). If they have the same length it's a triangle or a square, else it is a triangle or rectangle. I dig more to find out which of them is it. I remove the shape and i repeat because there can be more than one figure.
Everything looks great, but i'm very new at this, and i ned help on implementing this thing.
Can anyone, please, help me?

*Thank you!*

```
`    using System; 
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {      
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("img1.bmp");
                int h, w;
                h = bmp.Height;
                w = bmp.Width;

                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height); 

                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =bmp.LockBits
                 (rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                 bmp.PixelFormat);
    `
```

Comment: This is too broad.  Can you make your question more specific?  There are already questions about reading pixels from a bitmap.

Comment: Where? I didn't found something in C# to help me. How do I put every single pixel in a matrix?

Comment: Possibly result of search for "C# bitmap get pixel" may give you some hint how to get color of single pixel... I'm not sure if you need hints how to look for how to use "C# for loop" or "C# increment value by 1 with ++"... Also I suspect you are expected to read BMP format yourself...  Just ask your teacher to providing clarification on this post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Bitmap` has this method:

```
public Color GetPixel ( int x, int y );
```

Apart from that, it appears that determining whether the bitmap represents a triangle, square, or rectangle requires quite a bit more tenacity and resourcefulness than finding that method.  Are you sure you are up to it?